# Is there a Lightning component for inputRichText - with image upload?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience, inputfield

I'm looking for a lightning component that I can use that has the image upload capability. Similar to the Chatter WYSWG:

[image]

Note: I've used the **lightning:inputRichText (Beta)** and that doesn't have the image upload button..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There isn't one now, but it looks like one is coming in Summer 18. I just checked in my pre-release org and in v43.0 there is a new component called `lightning:insertImageButton` that can be used inside `lightning:inputRichText`

```
<aura:component>
    <lightning:inputRichText value="<b>HELLO</b>">
        <lightning:insertImageButton/>
    </lightning:inputRichText>
</aura:component>
```

Comment: Thanks! its really helps! Just switch to API version 43.0

Answer (score 1):

I found with the addition of  `<lightning:insertImageButton/>` that you get a strange-to-the-user error if you add a file larger than 1MB.  The error is

> This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it. First,
>   would you give us some details? (We're reporting this as error
>   ID:xxxx)

Inside the "Technical Stuff" you can see the following.

> Uncaught Error in $A.getCallback() [The image exceeded the maximum
>   size of 1 MB.] throws at
>   https://memsharp-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/bZa2QajUSmHCPiEKj7zMjw/aura_prod.js:34:15.
>   Caused by: Error in $A.getCallback() [The image exceeded the maximum
>   size of 1 MB.]
>   Object.uploadAndInsertSelectedFile()@https://memsharp-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/components/lightning/quillLib.js:2:231657
>   eval()@https://memsharp-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/components/lightning/insertImageButton.js:2:445
>   HTMLInputElement.eval()@https://memsharp-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/components/lightning/insertImageButton.js:3:283

The dialog offers to send in a report to SF so I asked them to pass this error onto us developers so we can handle it in a more graceful way for the user.

Should be clear: Summer 18 developer edition.